# Can't get join query in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I got elasticsearch version 7.3 and two indexes, `profiles` and `purchases`,
here is their mappings:

```
\purchases
{
    "purchases": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "product": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "profile": {
                    "type": "join",
                    "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                    "relations": {
                        "profiles": "purchases"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

\profiles
{
    "profiles": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "user": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added one profile with `user:abc, _id:1` and two purchases this way

```
{
    "profile": {"name": "profiles", "parent": "1"},
    "product" : "tomato",
}
{
    "profile": {"name": "profiles", "parent": "1"},
    "product" : "tomato 2",
}
```

Then I do search query for purchases

```
{
    "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "profiles",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "user:abc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get empty result, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of the [Join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) you can **not** create parent-child-relationships over multiple indices:

> The join datatype is a special field that creates parent/child relation within documents of the **same index**.

If you would like to use the join datatype, you have to model it in **one index**.

**UPDATE**

This is how your mapping and the Indexing of the documents would look like:

```
PUT profiles-purchases-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "product":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "profile":{
        "type": "join",
        "relations":{
          "profiles": "purchases"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index parent document:

```
PUT profiles-purchases-index/_doc/1
{
  "user": "abc",
  "profile": "profiles"
}
```

Index child documents:

```
PUT profiles-purchases-index/_doc/2?routing=1
{
  "product": "tomato",
  "profile":{
    "name": "purchases",
    "parent": 1
  }
}

PUT profiles-purchases-index/_doc/3?routing=1
{
  "product": "tomato 2",
  "profile":{
    "name": "purchases",
    "parent": 1
  }
}
```

Run Query:

```
GET profiles-purchases-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "profiles",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "user": "abc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  ...
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "profiles-purchases-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "1",
        "_source" : {
          "product" : "tomato",
          "profile" : {
            "name" : "purchases",
            "parent" : 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "profiles-purchases-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "1",
        "_source" : {
          "product" : "tomato 2",
          "profile" : {
            "name" : "purchases",
            "parent" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that you have to set the routing parameter to index the child documents. But please refer to the documentation for that.

Comment: Do you mean two types in the same index?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the example on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html

Comment: ok thanks, what should I do in my case with purchases and profiles?